# web.config location does not work in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, web-config

I have an MVC3 website published to my dev server. The authentication for this web site is set as below
Anonymous - Disabled
Windows - Enabled
Forms - Enabled
Impersonation - Enabled

I use Forms authentication in my website. To allow anonymous access to Content folder (all images, styles are available here), I added location tags in the root web.config file.

When I try to access my image http://devserver/website/Content/images/logo.png, it redirects me to login page.

> If I set Anonymous - Enabled in IIS, then i can access image.
>   Otherwise not. But I don't want to do this, since I cannot display the locally logged in username directly in username text box, if anonymous access is enabled.

I also tried to add web.config file with below contents

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="BlockViewHandler" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

in Content folder. This also does not seem to help. Any suggestions?

Is setting Anonymous - Enabled the only way to allow anonymous access to my website.

I have an ASP.net website with similar configuration
1. Anonymous - Disabled, Windows - Enabled, Impersonate - Enabled
2. location tags in root web.config file.
and it works perfectly.

I do not understand why the same does not work in MVC3. Can I add some file type exclusions(*.css, *.jpg, *.png) like in other PHP MVC3 framework.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend to enable anonymous requests.

If you need to secure a page in ASP.NET MVC then you need to use the [Authorize] attribute. You can put it on the controller or on the action declaration.

Examples:

```
[Authorize]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
  // All actions will be authenticated
  ...
}

public class HomeController : Controller
{
  public ActionResult EveryoneAllowed() {...}

  [Authorize]
  public ActionResult OnlyAuthenticated() {...}
}
```